# pandasObject.index() Vs reindexing using series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series, reindex

The functionality of reindexing in python pandas can also be done python Series as below.

```
import pandas as pd
order = ['a','c','b']
series_data = pd.Series([1,2,3],index=order)
series_data
```

In that case why do we explicitly go for reindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example using `index` available in `Series`

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['k','f','t'])
s
# k    1
# f    2
# t    3
# dtype: int64
```

We can state that above series got assigned index with a datatype of `int64`.

---

Now let's proceed with `reindex`:

```
order = ['k','c','b']
s.reindex(order)
# k    1.0
# c    NaN
# b    NaN
# dtype: float64
```

As you can observe we passed two new index `c` and `b` which were not there in original series, so those values are assigned equal to `NaN`. Since `NaN` has `dtype` of `float64`, hence a final series results into only three indexes `k, c and b` with `dtype` as `float64`.

I hope this clears how `index` inside `Series` is different from `reindex` outside.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer below link to understand about reindexing.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_reindexing.htm

Comment: On this site, the answer comes from you, not an external link.